# Best way to read data exactly once in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to label a test set with Tensorflow, which requires that I iterate over the set exactly once. Usually, I would pad out my number of examples to be a multiple of my batch size, but in this case I am using Tensorflow's queues in order to read data which is split over hundreds of files. When it reaches the final batch, there are not enough examples for one batch, and the program terminates. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I recommend you to check tensorflow's mnist example. At next_batch() function in input_data.py, they shuffle the order of data first and then pick data for a batch. When it gets the end of sample, shuffle again and pick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was using `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` for both my train and validation datasets, so I switched to using `tf.train.batch()` for validation. Because the number of examples is not an exact multiple of the batch size, the final batch will have some examples that have already been processed. I keep a set of example IDs that I have already labeled in order to discard duplicates.